# How to encode time in the range of 1 to 48

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have following time format with time interval of half hour in 24 HOUR, i.e 48 intervals in a day.

[image]

And I want to encode it in following format.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary created by [`timedelta_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.timedelta_range.html) and `zip`, for same types of data is necessary convert column [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['00:00:00','00:30:00','01:00:00','08:00:00']})

print (type(df['Time'].iat[0]))
<class 'str'>

d = dict(zip(pd.timedelta_range('00:00:00', '23:30:00', freq='30T'), range(1, 49)))
df['EncodedTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).map(d)
print (df)
       Time  EncodedTime
0  00:00:00            1
1  00:30:00            2
2  01:00:00            3
3  08:00:00           17
```

Similar solution created by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
d = dict(zip(pd.date_range('00:00:00', '23:30:00', freq='30T').strftime('%H:%M:%S'), 
             range(1, 49)))
df['EncodedTime'] = df['Time'].map(d)
```

---

Solution working with times:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':pd.to_datetime(['00:00:00','00:30:00','01:00:00','08:00:00']).time})

print (type(df['Time'].iat[0]))
<class 'datetime.time'>

d = dict(zip(pd.date_range('00:00:00', '23:30:00', freq='30T').time, range(1, 49)))
df['EncodedTime'] = df['Time'].map(d)
```

Comment: your code only numbers from 1 to ~ , it doesn't encode from 1 to 48.

Comment: @NikhilMangire - OK, so check another solution.

Comment: @NikhilMangire - Added next 2 solutions, it still some problem, what return `print (type(df['Time'].iat[0]))` ?